# Is there a way to use latex \cite{reference} in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, latex

I am using QuickLatex plugin and it works great. But when I tried to cite some references using \cite{paper1}, it did not seem work.

```
[latexpage]
Here is a citation \cite{example}.

\begin{thebibliography}

\bibitem{example}
Robert C. Merton, On the Pricing of Corporate Debt: The Risk Structure of Interest Rates. \textit{Journal of Finance} 1974; \textbf{2}:449–470.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Any help?

Comment: It looks like the QuickLatex doesn't support it, maybe this is something that you could use:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/papercite/

Comment: Is there any other solution? Using papercite, I will have to upload a seperate bibtex file to the server. If I need to use \cite{} in every my post, this approach is not very efficient.

Comment: This is not supported by QuickLaTeX, yet, see http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/#comment-10271

Answer (score 1):

Outside of using other plugins, as mentioned in the comments, you would need to essentially parse the LaTeX yourself by filtering `the_content`.

Here is a *very rough* example of how you might capture and transform the post content to parse a bibliography. Please note that I don't know LaTeX, and this is just string parsing. Also, I'm tracking citations and references in the arrays `$citations` and `$citation_refs` in case that is useful to you, but it may not be.

```
#add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_latex_citation_filter' );

function my_latex_citation_filter( $content ) {
    $lines = explode( "\n", $content );

    $citation_refs = [];
    $citations     = [];
    $next_is_ref   = false;
    $next_ref      = '';
    $in_bib        = false;

    foreach ( $lines as $index => $line ) {
        preg_match( '/\\\cite\{([^}]+)\}/', $line, $matches );

        if ( ! empty( $matches[1] ) ) {
            $citation_refs[] = $matches[1];
            $next_ref        = "citation-{$matches[1]}";
            $lines[ $index ] = str_replace( $matches[0], sprintf( '<a href="#%1$s">%2$s</a>', $next_ref, $matches[1] ), $line );
        }

        if ( $next_is_ref && $next_ref ) {
            $lines[ $index ] = sprintf( '<span id="%s">' . $line . '</span>', $next_ref );
            $next_ref        = '';
            $next_is_ref     = false;
        }

        preg_match( '/\\\bibitem\{([^}]+)\}/', $line, $matches );

        if ( ! empty( $matches[1] ) ) {
            $citations[] = $matches[1];
            $next_is_ref = true;
            unset( $lines[ $index ] );
        }
    }

    return implode( "\n", $lines );
}


$content = '
[latexpage]
Here is a citation \cite{example}.

\begin{thebibliography}

\bibitem{example}
Robert C. Merton, On the Pricing of Corporate Debt: The Risk Structure of Interest Rates. \textit{Journal of Finance} 1974; \textbf{2}:449–470.

\end{thebibliography}
';

echo my_latex_citation_filter( $content );
```

Uncomment the line at the top (`#add_filter...`) and remove the last line `echo ...` to use this as a filter on `the_content`, but the code as-is above can be run inside of a standalone PHP file to see how it works. The output of the above is:

```
[latexpage]
Here is a citation <a href="#citation-example">example</a>.

\begin{thebibliography}

<span id="citation-example">Robert C. Merton, On the Pricing of Corporate Debt: The Risk Structure of Interest Rates. \textit{Journal of Finance} 1974; \textbf{2}:449–470.</span>

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Also please note that I had to triple-escape the slashes for some reason, e.g. `\\\cite`. I'm not sure why, but my PHP wouldn't parse the `\cite` or `\bibitem` items otherwise. YMMV